# What benefits has a Stateful over a Stateless approach for a Jhipster Monolith App?

Tags: jhipster

I'm reading about stateful and stateless apps in Jhipster and it looks to me that for a monolith app, JWT (stateless app) is ligther, faster and easier so it looks like it's a better approach, but I would like to know if there is any benefit (and why) to a stateful approach on a monolith app.

Thanks

Comment: Why did you tag with jhipster-registry?

Comment: Thanks @Gaël, probably becasuse I'm not a programmer and I mix things in my head every now and then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improved security due to secure http-only cookies versus storing token in LocalStorage and SessionStorage in browser.

Also being stateful is not really a scalability issue as long as you store a limited amount of objects in Session: usually security related objects and avoid business logic objects.

Comment: Thanks again @Gaël, so you would say you prefer stateful https for a monolithic app? What would you say that are the benefits of a stateless app?

Comment: Yes because I went through security audits. I don't see any obvious benefit of stateless monoliths, stateless microservices are useful for scalability.

Answer (score 2):

There is a paradigm which is called [monolith first](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/MonolithFirst.html) introduced by martin fowler which means you go with monolith application until your business requires splitting to micro-services which then you step by step change your architecture to micro-service. If you have a monolith application you are fine using a stateful approach which then your only instance save some data on its own bundle in memory. But when you need to horizontally scale your app(multiple instances of your monolithic app) then you have to be stateless which is really easy to change to by using databases as state holders or some key/value storages like Redis or Memcached.